# Async Controller Progress Request Pending in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to get the percentage of Ajax requests processed at Mvc. I learned that this should be done with AsyncController.
But when the first request worked, I did not get the percentage because it was on the **TaskProgress** tail.

Controller:

```
public class AsyncTestController : AsyncController
{
    public void TaskAsync(int id)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(taskId =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                HttpContext.Application["task" + taskId] = i;
            }
            var result = "result";
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = result;
            return result;
        }, id);
    }

    public ActionResult TaskCompleted(string result)
    {
        return Content(result, "text/plain");
    }

    public ActionResult TaskProgress(int id)
    {
        string asd = HttpContext.Application["task" + id].ToString();
        return Json(new
        {
            Progress = HttpContext.Application["task" + id]
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View (javascript):

```
function async_test_start() {

    var taskId = 543;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/IK/AsyncTest/task/")',
        data: { id: taskId },
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        success: function (dt) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
            console.log(dt);
        }
    });

    var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/IK/AsyncTest/taskprogress/")',
            data: { id: taskId },
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            success: function (dt) {
                console.log(dt.Progress + '%');
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
}
```

Result (when ajax request starts):

[image: browser console]

[image: browser network]